# Error: Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, string

Firstly I am randomly selecting the ID from my table. That part works fine but the next part doesn't. The next part is selecting the ID's row, e.g. if the ID is 6, then it should select all the fields related to 6.

my table is like this:

```
------------------------------
|ID|Name|Email      |Password|
------------------------------
|1 |Amy |H@gmail.com|jaaaaaaa|
------------------------------
|2 |Bob |1@gmail.com|haaukanm|
------------------------------
|3 |Bill|aa@mail.com|fsoji443|
------------------------------
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

//select a number between min id and max id
$v = "SELECT ID FROM `tblaccounts` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $v);
$data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//var_dump($data2);

$c = "SELECT * FROM `tblaccounts` WHERE ID='$data2'";
$cresult = mysqli_query($connection, $c);
$data3 = mysqli_fetch_array($cresult);
var_dump($data3);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `$data2` is an array, this is should work

```
include('connect.php');

//select a number between min id and max id
$v = "SELECT ID FROM `tblaccounts` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $v);
$data2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

//var_dump($data2);
$c = "SELECT * FROM `tblaccounts` WHERE ID='".$data2['ID']."'";
$cresult = mysqli_query($connection, $c);
$data3 = mysqli_fetch_array($cresult);
var_dump($data3);
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is here:

```
$c = "SELECT * FROM `tblaccounts` WHERE ID='$data2'";
```

here `$data2` is not a single value, its an array and you are trying to compare it in `WHERE` like a string, that's why the error. Instead try `$data2['id']` like:

```
$c = "SELECT * FROM `tblaccounts` WHERE ID='".$data2['ID']."'";
```

or

```
$c = "SELECT * FROM `tblaccounts` WHERE ID=".$data2['ID'];  // Sinlge quote is not required if `ID` is `int`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error as you are comparing `array` in where clasue.
Your $data is an array like below

```
$data = array(
             'ID'=>2
             'Name'=>'Bob',
             'Email'=>'1@gmail.com',
             'Password'=>'haaukanm'

       );// say record with id 2 is fecthed
```

So use `$data['ID']` in your where clause